# JSON keys and bash variables in a loop

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to capture all the spaces/chat-rooms they use and ensure the new accounts get connected to all those spaces. I can use `curl` to call the service Spark API and get the list of spaces, and process that with `jq` to put it in a respectable format.  What I end up with is a series of 50 to 900 (depending on the use) JSON objects (one per space/room).

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "id":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNGY0Y2Q5NDAtN2JkZi0xMWU4LThiMjMtMTU0YzAyNTI0YzBh",
         "title":"(CISCO INTERNAL): FTB - CMS Opportunity",
         "type":"group",
         "isLocked":false,
         "lastActivity":"2018-06-29T21:05:55.994Z",
         "creatorId":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS9kMWI3MDRhNS05ZmU0LTQ3MTYtOGY2Zi02OGEyNjVjZGQ5YzM",
         "created":"2018-06-29T20:59:27.316Z"
      },
      {  
         "id":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vMTQxODk5MTAtN2JiYS0xMWU4LThiOWUtMjMwOWM4Y2NiYWMz",
         "title":"USU Cisco Webex EDU Program",
         "type":"group",
         "isLocked":true,
         "lastActivity":"2018-06-29T19:46:14.993Z",
         "creatorId":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS8wZThjMzg3Yy0zNzc5LTRlYTEtYmY2My1mNzZmMDJkYzVjM2M",
         "created":"2018-06-29T16:32:56.609Z"
      },
      {  
         "id":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vZjYyNDg1NjAtNzg5Yy0xMWU4LTlmYzItNGZhYzQwZWE4MTA4",
         "title":"Darren TeamSpace Space",
         "type":"group",
         "isLocked":false,
         "lastActivity":"2018-06-26T15:00:03.332Z",
         "teamId":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1RFQU0vZWQ5Mzc1ZDAtZjE1MC0xMWU1LWFjNWUtNTNiMzQxMDkxMTU1",
         "creatorId":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS83YTBkMTJiMS1lODMxLTRkNmItYTAzMS0xMDU4Y2UwOTAwZTU",
         "created":"2018-06-25T17:26:57.561Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I'd like to do here is create a quick and dirty script that can then process this JSON file in a loop, pulling the keys in as variables

```
(items.id = $id, items.title = $title, etc.)
```

with the associated values from the file, so I can perform some basic "if then else" evaluations (check if `isLocked` is `true` or `false`) and then execute some other API calls using the other variables.  For some reason, and it's probably my lack of familiarity with `jq`, I can't get the loop and variable extraction to work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to *loop* over the JSON objects here, using `jq`, you could just interpolate the variable inside each object and do your logic as needed. Since the fields in the JSON could contain spaces between them using a custom delimiter `|` to split them and use that in the `read` command of the `bash` loop

```
jq --raw-output '.items[] | "\(.id)|\(.title)|\(.isLocked)"' json |
    while IFS="|" read -r id title flag; do
        printf '%s|%s|%s\n' "$id" "$title" "$flag"
    done
```

Do what ever with the variables `id`, `title` and `flag` in the shell context now. If you want to use more variables, just add them to the original `jq` filter.

If you don't want the loop to run in a sub-shell, use the process substitution technique provided by the `bash` shell. Doing it runs in the same parent shell and makes the output of commands under `<(cmd)` as if it were appear in a temporary file

```
while IFS="|" read -r id title flag; do
    printf '%s|%s|%s\n' "$id" "$title" "$flag"
done< <(jq --raw-output '.items[] | "\(.id)|\(.title)|\(.isLocked)"' json)
```